# Cannot rename a file containing spaces and special characters on NTFS partition from Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, ntfs, file-management, ntfs-3g

I have both Windows 7 and Kubuntu installed on a computer. They both have access to a NTFS partition. I don't know how that happened, but I now have a directory containing weird characters: `Bases de donnÃ©es`, on this partition. The proper name should be `Bases de données`. When I noticed this, I was running the Linux OS; (I am assuming that) the problem is that I tried renaming that file from there.

First of all, here is how the NTFS drive is mounted through `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=...  /data  ntfs-3g  rw,users,auto,noexec,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0111,dmask=0  0  0
```

I cannot get to rename this particular file, which messes things up: in the command line, I got the following error:

```
mv: cannot move `Bases de donnÃ©es/' to `Bases de données': Input/output error
```

Dolphin gave me an error of the same spirit. But despite this error, the directory *seems* to be copied: I now end up with two directories: `Bases de donnÃ©es` and `Bases de données`.

In order to fix the issue, I booted on Windows, but I now have a problem removing the "duplicated" folder: I get the following error (I don't have enough reputation to upload an image directly, [here is the screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/80apv0yej/)):

```
Error 0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

I can still open the files within the directories without a problem. In an attempt to diagnose the problem, I did create a directory with the same name (with the `Ã©`) in `/tmp` and tried renaming it, and this did not reproduce the symptom. Also, running `ntfsfix` did not solve the issue.

I would really appreciate some help to diagnose and fix this problem! Thanks!

Comment: Try `chkdsk /f`? And may be [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/download.php?l=ru) is able to rename/delete this folder.

Comment: I generally refrain from using the norwegian æ, ø, å and the whole Russian alphabet for filenames to avoid headaches. The answers provided in [this entry](http://serverfault.com/questions/87055/change-filesystem-encoding-to-utf-8-in-ubuntu) on serverfault may help you

Comment: Indeed, `chkdsk /f` did solve my problem, thanks! Should have thought of that beforehand...